# How should I decide what deinterlacer to choose for streaming video?

Tags: kodi

In my pulldownmenu (Live TV xbmcI) for deinterlacers I can choose from for example bilinear, bicubic, etc.
Here you can see my options: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Video_playback.  (
I don't have Yadif only Lanczos3.)

It's hard to decide witch one I should choose

Is there a recommended deinterlancer with overall good quality?
What they all do?

Comment: Before someone votes to close as not constructive, please think about whether this question can be answered with specific expertise.

Comment: @slhck - I see no question here that the OP can't answer himself by trying the different deinterlancers and deciding for himself. And as such I vote to close as not constructive.

Comment: After a bit of thinking I edited this question rather heavily. In my opinion it perhaps no longer needs to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given multiple choices because there is no one-size-fits-all answer. Which filter you want to use depends on the performance of your machine and the content it's being fed.

Provided heat and power consumption are not an issue, you should probably use the most intensive filter you can without causing stuttery playback. Try Yadif (if it's there) over bicubic over billinear.

Comment: Sorry, it's for video not for live tv. So yadif is a good one? The default is bilinear.

Comment: It being live makes no difference to the potential performance impacts and visual benefits of de-interlacing. Yadif is good for most content but can create unpleasant additional glitches on heavily-compressed video. If your machine can handle it, use what looks best on the video you're watching.